# ASP.NET 5 Process.Start?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to use [`Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx) in an ASP.NET Beta8 project that I would like to be able to run on Linux using .Net core. Visual studio is giving me an error at compile time:

`Error  CS0103  The name 'Process' does not exist in the current context`

Going back and hovering my mouse over `Process.Start` I can see a message that says "DNX core 5.0 not available". Is there a different way of invoking processes in asp.net 5? Or perhaps this isn't possible yet?

Here is exactly how I am using it:

```
var p = Process.Start("someprog", "someargs");
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: It is in the source code [for .Net Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.cs#L1095)

Comment: So it is... So I guess my question now is why can I not use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So it was me not really not knowing how the new project system works for .net. I needed to add a dependency to my project.json:

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Diagnostics.Process": "4.1.0-beta-23409"
      }
    }
  },
```

Adding this made it compile. Although I am not sure if that version number is correct.

Comment: Currently still resolves to version "4.1.0" on Core 1.0.1